# Within the MapReduce implementation, are reduce functions indexed similarly to map functions?

Tags: view, mapreduce, couchdb

If I have a couple docs in Couch that look like this:

```
{
   "_id": "be890e3ee1457e920f12722c44001b0e", // Or whatever auto ID
   "_rev": "7-74d1787aa3ca6d2526c4436577da660f", // Or whatever auto rev
   "type_": "count",
   "value": -1,
   "time": 1485759832925 // This is an Epoch time, the result of this JavaScript: var x = (new Date()).getTime(), that I calculate in the console just before saving the doc
}
```

And then I create a map function to retrieve these docs like so (that I run directly after creating a few docs):

```
function(doc) {
    if (doc.type_) {
        if (doc.time) {
            var datetime = (new Date()).getTime();
            var docTime = doc.time;
            var docAge = datetime - docTime;
            // Only emit docs younger than 1 minute
            if (docAge / 1000 <= 60) {
                emit(doc.time, docAge);
            };
        };
    };
};
```

I found that once the view is calculated, that the `docAge` will never change and that the docs will always be emitted despite being 'too old'.

If you open a doc and re-save it, then the view will NOT emit that doc (because it reflects as a CouchDB update and now the time value is too old), but other docs will not have been recalculated (i.e. the docAge for those docs is still the same).

So by this I can see that views are incrementally updated to reflect changed docs. And as I understand, they are cached.

Question:

1. Where are these cached views stored?
2. Are Group and reduce output recalculated from scratch everytime the map
   function incrementally updates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your views are not being "cached" per-se. The idea behind CouchDB views is that they are deterministic, and thus should not be influenced by anything beyond the document in question.

Using `new Date()` in your view means that you are bringing in an external resource (the clock) which means your view index will be computed in a way you aren't intending based on your question.

Your map function must deal in absolutes, so it should output the timestamp irregardless of the time that your view index is rebuilt. From your application, you'll pass the time you want to query as a parameter to the view query.

For example, consider this view function:

```
function (doc) {
  if (doc.type_ && doc.time) {
    emit(doc.time);
  }
}
```

It will output the time for all your documents. Then, you will query the view passing in the expected timeframe.

```
?start_key=<timestamp from 1 minute ago>
```

Then you will get the documents whose timestamp falls in the last minute. You can include `end_key` to specify an upper-limit.

There's a bit of a mental hurdle to overcome with how MapReduce views in CouchDB are designed to work, so I would highly recommend their [Guide to Views](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/couchapp/views/intro.html) to get started. (in fact, their newest documentation is quite good and I would highly recommend reading through all of it)

Comment: When you say views are not 'cached' per say, where is the output being stored and how? I'm aware of how to query Couch using view, the above is a theoretical example to highlight my question. Which is basically "how does Couch handle view output"

Comment: What I mean to say is that your view is being computed and stored, which is different from being cached. A cache implies that it is temporary and can expire, whereas the index couch builds is intended to be deterministic. (which is why external factors like "current time" don't fit in the MapReduce paradigm couch uses)

Comment: Thank you. Do you know where the view output is stored? Just for interest sake... Is it in the db file or a separate file?

Comment: Ah yeah, if you look in `/var/lib/couchdb`, you'll find files with the `.view` extension, these are the files where the computed view index is stored.

Comment: The exact location may vary depending on your platform, it could live in `/usr/local/var/lib/couchdb` for example. You'll find your database files in the same place, they have a `.couch` extension.